# Regular expression for restricting the length

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression

```
^[\\p{L}\\d._]*\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\d._]*$
```

which accepts alphabets,alphanumerics and special characters like . and _ . Can we make this regular expression accept total minimum length of three(including characters,alphanumerics etc)  and maximum of 15(including characters,alphanumerics etc)

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: I would use `if (pass.length() < 3 || pass.length() > 15) invalidLength();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an extra check that the total length is between 3 and 15 you can use lookahead:

```
(?=^.{3,15}$)^[\\p{L}\\d._]*\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\d._]*$
```

A group of the form `(?=<regex>)` checks if `<regex>` matches from the current position, but doesn't move the marker forward.

Comment: +1 It's so easy that it hurts that I didn't think about it before

Comment: Hi, Im not sure, somehow it is not working to accept minimum 3 and maximum of 15,anyways thanks

Comment: @balaji: Can you add a few test cases that should and shouldn't work to the question?

Comment: Valid                                                                    1. ABC123de (alphanumeric- irrespective of the case)
2. ABCDEfgh (only alphabets – irrespective of the case)
3. Abc_.123 (only special characters allowed are _ and .)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
^[\p{L}\d._]*\p{L}+[\p{L}\d._]{3,15}
```

Comment: I tried this but somehow it is not working for accepting minimum 3  and maximum 15

Comment: There should be a `$` at the end of that.